# how to send and receive data from nodemcu?

Tags: android, bluetooth, textview, communication, nodemcu

I want to develope android studio application which send data to nodemcu and also I want to receive data to android textview.
Or the same functionality using Bluetooth module. Because using Bluetooth module I can control led using android application..but I don't know how to receive it on the android application.
Can anyone please help?

Comment: there are 2 ways to communicate with bluetooth, 
[Bluetooth](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth) and [Ble](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le)

Comment: I want to use Bluetooth module

Comment: please provide any code snippet if possible or idea related to receiving data from nodemcu to android app

Answer (score 1):

If you want to connect with `classic bluetooth`, then you need to do some stuff.

(Suppose you have paired device already, or you can paired directly by device's Settings)

1. scan device with [BluetoothAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter) from [BluetoothManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothManager)

   `val bluetoothManager = context.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE)`

   `val bluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.adapter`

---

2. get the device you want to communicate with form [BluetoothAdapter.bondedDevices](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter#getBondedDevices())

   `val bondedDevices = bluetoothAdapter.bondedDevices`

   `val device = bondedDevices[any]`  (bondedDevices type is Set)

---

3. call [createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice#createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(java.util.UUID)) to create a `Socket` connection

   `val socket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord()`

---

4. after `connect` the socket, you can send/retrieve with `outputstream/inputstream` from this socket, and finally `disconnect` the connection.

   `socket.connect()`

   `...`

   `your comminucation here with socket.inputstream()/socket.outputStream()`

   `...`

   `socket.disconnect()`